# Facebook site data not scraped - but debug does

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api

I have read lot of reference and i am not able to find the problem in my code.

If i copy and paste my url, Facebook is not scraping the content in my url.

I have the following in my code.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<meta property="og:title" content="Title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="mysite link" />
<meta property="og:image" content="image full path" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SIte name" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="admin id for the site"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Site description" />
```

If i copy and paste my link in facebook wall, It tries to scrape. The loading bar is running and then it does nothing. So i tested my site in debug tool.

The tool gave the title, image, description and everything.
What mistake do you see in my side?